# convergence question

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $p > 0$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty  } (n^{p})^{1/n} = 1$

You may use that the function $f(x) = x^{p}$ is continuous at $x = 1$.

I know that I have to show that $ \left |(n^{p})^{1/n}-1\right | \leq  \varepsilon$, but I am not sure how

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)=x^p$ is continuous at $x=1$, it suffices to show $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}=1$. Prove: for any $\delta>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $n<(1+\delta)^n$ if $n>N$ (Hint: If $n$ is an integer you may use Binomial theorem).

Answer (score 2):

By the l'Hospital theorem we have easily
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log n}{n}=0$$
hence we find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n^p\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\log (n^p)}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{p\frac{\log (n)}{n}}=e^0=1$$